# Codename One SMS BroadcastReceiver and Service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, codenameone

I'm considering using Codename One to try to leverage my code into iOS, but it's not clear I can even write my current Android project in Codename One.

My app listens for inputs via GoogleCloudMessaging, via SMS using a BroadcastReceiver and via LAN by implementing a Service (android.app.Service.)  It also writes to Dropbox using the 3rd party CloudRail library.

If I've understood the docs, none of these are readily supported by Codename One, correct?  Is my app a bit too platform-specific to be portable to Codename One?

Comment: Since this is platform specific, you could achieve it through the Native Interface. As for the DropBox, there's an SDK for that... https://github.com/chen-fishbein/dropbox-codenameone-sdk

Comment: My understanding is that the chen-fishbein library hasn't been touched in three years, only handles the deprecated OAUTH1, and doesn't write to the dropbox.

Can the native interface handle service functionality making calls back into the Codename One code?

Comment: Yes, it should be able to.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive push messages in Codename One but GCM is probably not the right fit for iOS so you would receive them via APNS and that goes thru our servers to abstract the OS differences.

I'm not sure what you mean by "lan" do you mean you listen to UDP broadcasts? We support TCP sockets but never got into the UDP part as it's not as common or portable (there are some complexities regarding low level posix calls). You can probably do an abstraction by taking the cn1lib for tcp sockets written by Steve Hannah and use that as your starting point.

We have dropbox read support but not dropbox write, this should be doable.

Background services don't exist on platforms other than Android and as you are probably aware are undergoing behavioral changes with newer Android versions to preserve battery life.

If something is possible on iOS you can probably accomplish it on Codename One, however if your app is really low level then Codename One is probably not the ideal fit.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't think of the app as "really low level", but it isn't just a javascript web page.  It does serve as essentially a receiver of various kinds of messages, including as almost a web server, as well as writing to DropBox, using speech synthesis and the camera.

How "low level" is "really low level"?

Comment: We don't have abstractions for quite a lot of these things out of the box. E.g we use speech synthesis in the Dr.Sbaitso demo and we do it via native interfaces as we never created an abstraction for that. So you can do all of the things you mentioned but the question is what would be the ratio of native code/Codename One code. It's really hard for me to tell off the bat as our abstractions are mostly aimed for "typical business apps" which is pretty vague and generally means: "users complain functionality X is missing so we add it". I think we don't have enough users with your use cases...